# Whether its a good practice to create super class for only split the code in java?

Tags: java

i know actual purpose of superclass and subclass (inheritance), they are meant for extending the behaviors of parent and multiple implementations of parent behavior. but coming to split the code. we can create another class and put some code on it and can call from main class. alternatively we can write some code on super class and another some in child class (only for the purpose of split the code), but is that a good practice.

like below?

```
class A{

void methA(){
....
....
}

void methB(){
......
...
}

}

class B extends A{

void methC(){

methA();
methB();
.
}
}
```

if its not good way,what is the way to fragment the code if its more that 1000 lines (more readable code)?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: The question is unclear. I could go on about when to split and when not to... but I would need a better example. Class 'A' and 'B' is not much to build on. Yes, there are cases when you should split. Yes, there are cases when you should not.

Comment: No             [15 chars required, but needed only 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always it is a matter of object oriented design and hence, depends on the concrete situation. But in general you may go with the following principles:

- use delegation in favor of inheritance, because inheritance restricts all other classes which like to use that behavior to one super class.
- try to keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't repeat yourself). If you define the same behavior in more then one place, you have to change those many places in case the requirements demand changing this behavior.
- if you inherit from another class, try to keep the visibility to the package if possible. Otherwise you may widen the interface of a package only for code-reuse and not for abstraction.
- ask yourself when you inherit from another class, if the [substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) applies. If not reconsider not to use inheritance (sometimes you still want to inherit anyways)

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to split code it's not needed B to extend A, they can be just two separate classes without parent-child relation between them. And B can call A. What you suggest is not really a good practice. For this approach to make sense, there must be at least one more class C which extends A and possibly changes A's behavior. If that's not the case, I would just implement one of these two approaches:

1) put all the methods in A;
2) have two unrelated classes A and B (that is
class B does not extend A), and have B call A
(that is use delegation and not inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

My usual way to do this:

do the things simple as possible.
When you get the feel an higher level of architecture is required then do it.
In time you will know when to use this abstraction but don't make your live harder for now reason while learning.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not good practice. Inheritance is used where you need special class of the base class. For example You have Car class its special classes will be BMW , Honda, Tyota. or you have Human class its specail classes are Male and Female. Or Shape its special classes are Circle , Rectangle , Square Triangle. So when your need or requirement is Specail class of base class then you may go for inheritance not just to split the code in two classes.

Answer (score 0):

No inheritance is not good for this scenario.

because split code i assume , will have different logic which is not relevant between 2 classes.

so inheritance will inherit the behaviour of parent class and consumes memory for parent attributes and methods.

so use it only if child also requires parent behaviour or else dont go for it.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. Best practice is to adhere to the principle of high cohesion, low coupling. This means that methods that "belong" together, stay together and that a class should depend on as few other classes as possible. By using inheritance to "split" code you are intentionally violating this principle for no apparent reason.

If it's because your class has become unmanageable, it's probably because it has too much responsibility, so you should look at a way to split it into two separate classes by responsibility, as explained by the Single Responsibility Principle.